# words stemming and save output to text file

Tags: python, nltk

i have this code its stemmed words from text file and save the output to another text file.
the problem is its just do stemming to the first word and ignore the others.
any help ?

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

with open(r'file path', 'r') as fp:
tokens = fp.readlines()

for t in tokens:
 s = stemmer.stem(t.strip())
  print(s, file=open("output.txt", "a"))
```

Comment: This is probably a pasting error, but do you notice how the indentations are not matching?

Comment: I'm sorry ,I don't  understand you

Comment: There are extra spaces before the import statements, and the context manager, are you aware of that?

Comment: they are like this because i make many spaces tp post them here, in the program there is no spaces

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest editing your question to remove the extra space. [See the Formatting Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: i remove the extra spaces

Comment: Um, now your indents are messed up after the for loop and the context manager.

Comment: what about now ?

Comment: is that help to find a solution ?

Comment: but h have another question. can i aske it or post another question?

Comment: Post another question. But what solved this problem?

Comment: the spaces was too much